# net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on an angular application deployed on IIS

Tags: angular, windows, iis

[image]
I have deplpoyed an angular 15 application on a IIS windows server, the problem is that when I acces the app from the server's localhost it works as expected but when i want to acces it from another ip adress it gives me the SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
I have not configured any Https in my app or in the IIS, it's just a dev server.
Any help ?

EDIT: I installed nginx, and served the application via it. but the problem persists.
Angular still fetches the dist files over https.
Still looking for a solution

Comment: You can try to clear Browser Cache, Cookies, and Reset SSL Cache and temporarily disable Antivirus and Firewall (Sometimes these software might incorrectly block a secure connection).

Comment: Hi, I have allready tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well , the problem was in the windows firewall. It was responsible for this type of error. Refer to this if it helps https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows_server_2012/windows_server_2012_firewall.htm